# Service Broker Queue Custom Reports

Tags: .net, service-broker

we have started research on Service Broker and planning to implement in application. But we are not getting how to display Statistics reports(in UI) containing:
1. No of messages in the queue.
2. No of Messages so for Executed/Completed.
3. No of messages IN Process, Waiting, Failed,etc
4. No of Conversations in Specific period of time,etc
etc etc....

Is there any possible way to fetch these information fully/partially

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Catalog views ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173780.aspx)). For example:

```
Select * From sys.service_queues
Select * From sys.transmission_queue
Select * From sys.conversation_groups
Select * From sys.conversation_endpoints
```

Use DMV ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176110.aspx)). For example:

```
SELECT spid, DB_NAME(database_id) database_name, OBJECT_NAME(queue_id) queue_name,
    procedure_name, execute_as
FROM sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks
WHERE database_id = DB_ID();

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) database_name, OBJECT_NAME(queue_id) queue_name,
    state, last_empty_rowset_time, last_activated_time, tasks_waiting
FROM sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors
WHERE database_id = DB_ID();
```

Use SQL Server Log. Can do also like this:

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1
```

Use reports in Management Studio. Go to "Service Broker" node, right click and then "Reports-> Standart Reports-> Service Broker Statistics"